# Project is not running in node latest version

Tags: node.js, npm

i have been working on a project, previously i was fine but after upgraded to node v8.9.4 my project is not working, it does not showing any errors none of the api's are running can please some one help

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "v2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -e html,css,js -i node_modules bin/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.4.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.5.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "bson": "^0.4.23",
    "compression": "^1.5.2",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.8.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "email-existence": "^0.1.5",
    "express": "^4.12.4",
    "express-session": "~1.11.3",
    "fb": "^1.1.1",
    "gm": "^1.18.1",
    "html-pdf": "^2.0.1",
    "image-size": "^0.5.0",
    "jimp": "^0.2.24",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.0.1",
    "mailcomposer": "^3.10.0",
    "mailgun": "^0.5.0",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.7.10",
    "mime": "^1.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "mongodb": "^1.4.38",
    "mongoskin": "^1.4.13",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "multer": "^1.0.3",
    "node-schedule": "^1.1.1",
    "nodemailer": "v0.7.1",
    "paperwork": "^2.1.1",
    "paypal-rest-sdk": "^1.6.8",
    "qs": "^4.0.0",
    "quick-pay": "^1.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "sharp": "^0.15.1",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.58.0",
    "striptags": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens on console when you type "node server.js" ?

Comment: it will run, but nothing  happening on console, when i tried to send any request `get` post` etc it keep on sending by i dont get any response

Comment: re-run `npm install` if you haven't. Maybe there is an issue with `node_modules`.

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` and `npm install`

Comment: i tried many times, but no luck, if it is an issue with `node_modules` then what can be the solution ? how can i solve ?:(